# Separate process sharing queue with main process (producer/consumer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm pretty new to multiprocessing in Python and I've done a lot of digging around, but can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. I have a bit of a consumer/producer problem where I have a simple server with an endpoint that consumes from a queue and a function that produces onto the queue. The queue can be full, so the producer doesn't always need to be running.

While the queue isn't full, I want the producer task to run but I don't want it to block the server from receiving or servicing requests. I tried using multithreading but this producing process is very slow and the GIL slows it down too much. I want the server to be running all the time, and whenever the queue is no longer full (something has been consumed), I want to kick off this producer task as a separate process and I want it to run until the queue is full again. What is the best way to share the queue so that the producer process can access the queue used by the main process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to share the queue so that the producer process can access the queue used by the main process?

If this is the important part of your question (which seems like it's actually several questions), then `multiprocessing.Queue` seems to be [exactly what you need](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html?#exchanging-objects-between-processes). I've used this in several projects to have multiple processes feed a queue for consumption by a separate process, so if that's what you're looking for, this should work.